# How to solve operator does not exist error in my postgresql update query?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table in postgresql db from my Python script but getting an error in below line-

```
update_query='update product_'+lang+' set "StockQuantity"='+str(item[1].StockQuantity )+' where "ProductId"='+str(item[1].ProductId)
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ... product_fr set "StockQuantity"=700 where "ProductId"=367945
                                                            ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You 
might need to add explicit type casts.
[SQL: 'update product_fr set "StockQuantity"=700 where 
"ProductId"=367945'] (Background on this error at: 
 http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I think issue is with my ProductId value in update query; I converted it to string but it's not working.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Sample query run in postgresql:

Not working query-

```
update public.product_fr set "StockQuantity"=1900 where "ProductId"=367945
```

Working Query-

```
update public.product_fr set "StockQuantity"=1900 where "ProductId"='367945'
```

Comment: What is the data type of ProductId? And why in the world are you wrapping column names in double quotes???

Comment: If I don't give value in quotes then postgresql don't take of case. In my table column names are case sensitive so I have to give value in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your ProductId is a text type, so you need to wrap the number is quotes so it’s a text type too.

```
update_query='update product_'+lang
  +' set "StockQuantity"='+str(item[1].StockQuantity )
  +' where "ProductId"=\''
  +str(item[1].ProductId) + '\''
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but I am unable to put quotes right in product id value. Can you please correct my update query:'update product_'+lang+' set "StockQuantity"='+str(item[1].StockQuantity )+' where "ProductId"='+str(item[1].ProductId)

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "productid" does not exist
LINE 1: update product_fr set StockQuantity=300 where ProductId='367...
                                                      ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "product_fr.ProductId".
 [SQL: "update product_fr set StockQuantity=300 where ProductId='367945'"]

Comment: I solved this issue by putting column names in quotes.